/usr/lib/python3.12 was accidentally deleted, is there way to recover?
In order to recover I tried apt autoremove, tried to reinstall python3, libpython3-stdlib, libpython3-minimal with apt and dpkg, tried to remove python files from /var/lib/dpkg/info. Neither of that helped. Every time I get the same message:
    Setting up python3 (3.12.6-1) ...
    running python rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
    running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
    Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
    Python path configuration:
      PYTHONHOME = (not set)
      PYTHONPATH = (not set)
      program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
      isolated = 0
      environment = 1
      user site = 1
      safe_path = 0
      import site = 1
      is in build tree = 0
      stdlib dir = '/usr/lib/python3.12'
      sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
      sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
      sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
      sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
      sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
      sys.prefix = '/usr'
      sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
      sys.path = [
        '/usr/lib/python312.zip',
        '/usr/lib/python3.12',
        '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
      ]
    Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
    Python runtime state: core initialized
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

    Current thread 0x00007fcbf087c080 (most recent call first):
      <no Python frame>
    dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
     installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     python3
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

OS: kali-rolling

tried to remove python files from /var/lib/dpkg/info Stop deleting things! That's how you ended up here in the first place.

To fix this, you need to re-install all your Python packages. Here’s a quick-and-dirty recipe:
sudo apt reinstall $(dpkg -l '*python*' | awk '/^ii/ { print $2 }')

You might need to run this several times until it completes without error.

Since Kali is a special-purpose distro for pentesting, and has no intention to be robust against mistakes, and is definitely not considering itself a long-term stable end-user distro, I think you'll find that compared to trying to repair this, you're not losing much if you just go ahead and use a fresh Kali image. You'd want to, of course, move your files (e.g., pentesting results) to external storage (USB stick, network storage), and then start with a fresh image.
(Really, make sure you're not abusing Kali for something it's not. If you need something to just browse, or develop on, or even inspect network services, most other distros are better tailored to your needs – Kali stresses it is meant for expert users in a very narrow, the covert pentesting, scenario. All tools you can find on Kali can also be built & installed on a regular debian, but the regular debian will behave more like a regular Linux system rather than a highly specialized tool.)

Related meta question on the subject of selecting to use Kali - Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?

@ChesterGillon I used to link to that a lot, but after reading https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5316/why-i-closed-the-why-is-kali-so-hard-question I don't like it as much anymore.
